# iOS and Java - How to decode UTF-8 encoded NSData on server programmed in Java?

Tags: java, ios, utf-8, nsdata, decode

I am sending JSON from my iPhone app to my server which is Play Framework's Java app and deployed on Heroku Cloud.

Here is my code i am using in my App.

```
self.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myURL.herokuapp.com/check/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Rajesh", @"pass", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username", @"password", nil]];
NSString *jsonString = [dict JSONRepresentation];

NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);

NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", data.description);

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
if(conn)
{
    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"%@", @"connection started");
}
```

Now as i have encoded the jsonString into NSData using utf-8 encoding. How to decode it on server side?

Strange issue is that If i try to fetch the body using `request.body().toString()` I am getting the following output.

```
DefaultRequestBody(Some(Map()),None,None,None,None,None,false)
```

When i made a same kind of request from my Android app i just used `request().body().asJson()` method and got the JSON which i used further but in iOS i am converting my Json into NSData before sending it to the server so i am bit confused about how i supposed to decode it at server side.

Comment: Why are you using POST request?? Is their anything special with it?? First of all try to point to server with GET request if it is working then go for POST request. Reason i am telling is I have face very strange issues with POST requests....

Comment: I tried that. Server working fine and sending result. Only thing i am having issue with is NSData. I don't know how to handle it in Java. I tried few methods but no luck so far. So i put everything in request header and passing it to server but i know it's not a safe practice. I am kind of stuck at the moment.

Comment: @Varundroid, did you find any way to solve this issue?